# Как написать регулярное выражение для разделение комманды?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, любой-язык

На входе строка запуска какого-либо приложения вида

```
C:\temp\filename.bat a=123 b -n
```

Если в пути присутствуют пробелы, то добавляются апострофы

```
"C:\temp\program files\filename.exe" -noselect dbrid="aaaa"
```

Нужно разделить на:

```
Диск     Приложение                          Параметры
C:\      temp\filename.bat                   a=123 b -n
C:\      temp\program files\filename.exe     -noselect dbrid="aaaa"
```

Пока не очень представляю как написать, что если вначале была ", то она должна и завершать и в этом случае допустимы пробелы в пути.
Можно конечно сделать как 2 шаблона и объеденить через | но наверняка можно сделать проще?

https://regex101.com/r/SmCBDA/1

Comment: Может, `(?:[^\s"]|"[^"]*")+`? [`См. пример работы выражения`](https://regex101.com/r/F4aRA6/1).

Comment: что-то близко. проблема в том, что между проверкой начальной ковычки и текстом у нас ещё один match с диском

Comment: Пока что `^(?|"([a-zA-Z]:\\)([^"]*)"|((?1))(\S+))\s*(.*)$` сойдёт ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/SmCBDA/2)).

Comment: `^(")?([a-zA-Z]:\\)((?(1)[^"]*|\S+))"?\s*(.*)$` ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/SmCBDA/5)) тоже.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ответом оформите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться "условным конструктом":

```
^(")?([a-zA-Z]:\\)((?(1)[^"]*|\S+))(?(1)")\s*(.*)$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/SmCBDA/6).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(")?` - Подмаска №1: кавычка (опционально, захватывающая подмаска тут необязательная, однако шаблон внутри неё обязателен)
- `([a-zA-Z]:\\)` - Подмаска №1: буква из набора символов ASCII и `:\`
- `((?(1)[^"]*|\S+))` - Подмаска №2: если подмаска №1 нашла совпадение, 0 и более символов, отличных от `"`, в противном случае 0 и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов
- `(?(1)")` - если подмаска №1 нашла совпадение, `"` (в противном случае ничего не требуется)
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `(.*)` - Подмаска №3: 0 и более символов, отличных от символов переноса строки
- `$` - конец строки.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, тут только через объединение и можно сделать.  Вот
пример для *POSIX sed*:

```sed
s/\([A-Z]:\\\)\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)\|"\([A-Z]:\\\)\(.*\)" \(.*\)/\1\4    \t\2\5    \t\3\6/
```

```sh
$ sed -f ./tmp.sed ./tmp.txt 
C:\     temp\filename.bat       a=123 b -n
C:\     temp\program files\filename.exe     -noselect dbrid="aaaa"
```

Вот пример для *Go*:

```golang
var re = regexp.MustCompilePOSIX(`([A-Z]:\\)([^ ]*) (.*)|"([A-Z]:\\)(.*)" (.*)`)
fmt.Printf("%#q\n", re.FindStringSubmatch(s))
```

Ссылка на *Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/xlvjoulzTuM.